# probability of getting one suit

Tags: probability

Qn : Cards are drawn one at a time, without replacement from a deck of 52 playing cards until only cards of one suit is left. What is the probability that the cards left are all diamonds?

Help in this question will be much appreciated. i have no clue as to how to even begin doing this question.

Comment: 1/4 due to symmetry?

Comment: The solution provided is very elegant. A simple symmetry argument helps us eschew complicated combinatorics !

Answer (score 1):

Rhetorical question as hint:

Would the probability that it are e.g. spades differ from the probability that it are diamonds?

Comment: So it is absolutely irrelevant to count the number of ways it is possible to have cards of only one suit remaining ?

Comment: @user230452 Indeed. There are $4$ candidates and they have equal probability to be "elected" as the remaining suite.

Comment: Wow. Nice observation.